# Infopath - get user properties (e-mail, department.. ) from a people picker - other than current user

Tags: 2013, infopath, user-profile-service, user, user-profile-property

I've tried to follow this link http://blogs.technet.com/b/anneste/archive/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx to get user properties, but I only get properties from my current user.

Is there a way to pick a user from a people picker and then populate the properties?

I found a youtube movie that does what I want but I it doesn't work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ev1a2wX-CAo . Could It be somthing with the environment?

Running Sharepoint 2013 , infopath 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand how InfoPath and User Profile data work together, you need to work your way through this [Clayton Cobb blog post](http://claytoncobb.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/)

Your eyes will wobble and your ears will shake, but if you follow this step by step, you will be on top of the game of every user profile related InfoPath lookup.

> > Is there a way to pick a user from a people picker and then populate the properties?

Yes. You need to get the selected user's details and feed it to the UPS query, then query the data connection, then return the property you want.

That's the one-liner. The article link above has the nitty gritty.

Comment: Something is wrong with the people-picker config. Seems like the people picker is getting resoults from wrong OU

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this uing the sharepoint Rest webservice. First, you create your list with a list with a "person" field as a column. Then, using that username, you can query all the rest of profile details using this call:

```
http://[site FQDN]/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='[domain\username]'
```

You could set a rule that once the person field is filled up/changed, query that data. Then, you could use the xml data returned to fill the rest of your list columns